# How to open specific controller when user taps on Push Notifications when App is NOT running (i.e Totally Killed) Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm able to send push notifications to my IOS device. But when I click on that notification it just opens the app.when my app is in background or in foreground it works perfectly, I want the app to open and navigate to a specific view controller depending on the push notification received.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    NSDictionary *apsDict = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *alertForegroundMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [apsDict objectForKey:@"alert"]];

    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 20 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       // Check result of your operation and call completion block with the result
                       completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

                       NSMutableArray *arrnotification;

                       arrnotification = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

                   });

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloadDataFromServer" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
          NSLog(@"User Info : %@",userInfo);
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"userInfo->%@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);
        NSDictionary *sentObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:noteDict,@"data", nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloadDataFromServer" object:sentObject];
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: is your navigate to a specific VC code written in  `downloadDataFromServer` function?

Comment: there is not push/present methods called to do the actual navigation. is it in one of the other methods?

Comment: @ CodeChanger-yes it navigate to a specific VC

Comment: Please do not use the Apple logo for your avatar: you aren't allowed to use it. See https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

Answer (score 0):

When the app gets launched after the user opens the app from the notification. The best way to handle navigation based on the notification is to check the `launchOptions` dictionary in the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method. This should contain the `remoteNotification`- key, which holds the push notification data.

As mentioned in the discussion section of `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` -method, [documentation](http://application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)), the system does not automatically launch your app.

[application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application)